# Safari Reader behavior is inconsistent

Tags: html, safari, reader

I have two HTML files, identical but for the content of their H1s and their ARTICLEs. Their structure is in general, HEAD with imbedded brief STYLE, HEADER styled with a logo background and containing an Address string styled, MAIN containing ARTICLE, H1 and text, FOOTER with three navigation Addresses. Simple-minded.

In one of the two, Safari Reader picks up the TITLE contents and displays it as H1.title in generated HTML. In the other, Safari Reader does not. Is there any possible reason why Safari Reader would behave differently in one file from what it does in another?

Comment: Put some code so that developers can understand it better

Comment: I'm not sure how to proceed, @bigcountry. Do you mean, post the entire contents of a web page? Before I litter this thread with the code of even smallest entire web page, 1713 bytes, I'm not sure whether you mean the whole shebang. There are two pages (one, 1713 bytes, the other  because of different content 3074 bytes). I doubt the entire contents would be appropriate to post. Please advise.

Comment: I wish Apple would provide explicit and easily-located documentation on the arcane topic of how to format HTML for Safari Reader. Specifics such as, what HTML elements may provoke the reader in various ways, and the number of characters in an HTML element that are required for that provocation.

Comment: If anyone can give a link, I'd truly appreciate it. Meanwhile, I'm solving my question through trial and error and will post no code here. (HTML elements with class "comment" are ignored, H1s have character count requirement, presence MAIN and ARTICLE sections help, and so on…)